# Mvvmcross inconsistent binding within viewmodel

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

I'm experiencing strange behaviour in binding of simple EditText controls within one viewmodel. For some of the properties, the binding works, for others it does not while i cannot discover any difference in the way the code is written (both in cs and axml files). What could cause such baheviour ? How can one debug binding triggering problems ? Code snippets of two properties below. The first one works, the second doesn't...

```
        private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => FirstName);

        }
    }

    private string _installer;
    public string Installer
    {
        get { return _installer; }
        set
        {
            _installer = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Installer);
        }
    }
```

axml :

```
                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstname"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    local:MvxBind="Text FirstName" />

                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/installer"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="Installer" 
                    Mvx.MvxBind="Text Installer"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: looks like I've just solved my own problem by looking at the question above. One uses local:MvxBind, the other Mvx.MvxBind... changing it all to loacl:MvxBind does the trick. I would still be interested to know understand the difference between the two as I notice they are used randomly in most of the examples

Comment: please add links to the samples where they are used randomly.

Comment: wil do if I come across them. What is the real difference ?

Comment: I don't believe they exist... when I see some then I'll let you know...